# Type a Svelte components property based on another properties value

Tags: typescript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

In the svelte component

```
<script lang="ts">
    export let multiple: boolean = false;
    export let value: string|string[];

    // ...
</script>

<!-- ... -->
```

the type of the `value` property should be `string` if `multiple == false` and `string[]` otherwise. How can this be achieved?

**Edit:** The idea is to get a [Discriminated Union](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions) effect for components.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the type of 'value' a conditional type. To do this you should declare a function that will determine and return the type for you. This can be done like so:

```
declare function f<T extends boolean>(x: T): T extends false ? string : string[];
```

Then you can have your props defined and the type of 'value' will be set to string unless the component declaration sets 'multiple' to true where the type of 'value' will become string[].

```
export let multiple: boolean = false;
export let value = f(multiple);
```

Comment: If I correctly understand your answer, the type of `value` is reffered by the return type of `f`. How does this differ to directly using something like `export let value: string|string[] = multiple ? [] : ''`.

But the problem seems still unsolved to me since `value` can be set from the outside of the component. In this case the typechecking still ought to work.

Comment: Using `let value: string|string[] = multiple ? [] : ''` still only sets `value` with a union type. The `f` function is necessary to make the type conditional. Because `value` and `multiple` are set from the parent the conditional type check should be in the parent component and in the child to completely avoid `value` being a union type.